# Parsing excel sheet UI side (react) vs Server side (java): what is the correct approach?

Tags: javascript, java

I need to parse excel sheets uploaded by user. What would be the correct place to parse it with pros and cons: server side [java] or UI side [react]

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse Excel sheets in Java using Apache POI library on server-side https://poi.apache.org/ and XSSF https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/. POI works with .xls files while XSSF only for .xslx.

I do not recommend parsing XLS files on client-side because they can be big and you will waste client resources (battery, cpu).

Comment: Wasting client cpu power instead of server can be a better scenario to scale to bigger usage :-) but I'll definitely prefer to code on backend rather than js. It will depend on the use case (ie. what to do with the data after the parsing is done)

Comment: I agree, but usually heavy client-side operations is not the case for mobile web browsers